# Accesibility features not loaded at startup?

Tags: 20.04, accessibility

Prior to the latest release, when I started Ubuntu, my accessibility settings would load and appear. Now, when I start Ubuntu, my accessibility settings are toggled on but are not actually working. I am having issues with the "Large Text" feature in the accessibility settings. I'm a developer myself but don't really know where to look in the code for this feature so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be happy to look at the code.